# An attempt to prove the parallel axiom

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

It is known that the parallel axiom has been proven independent of Euclidean geometry in the sense that its validity or falsity alike does not affect the validity of Euclidean geometry, but I have succeeded in proving its validity in Euclidean geometry, and I am not sure of the validity of the proof or its falsity. Is there a fallacy in the proof such as  Incognito circular reasoning, or is the evidence valid? I'll lay out the proof now:

Parallel lines do not intersect no matter how long they are
Proof:

[image]

$L⊥V$ in $A$, and $T⊥V$ in $B$, and therefore $L∥T$ because the two perpendiculars are parallel.
We know that for two non-separating lines if they intersect they will intersect at exactly one point, so if $L,T$ intersect at point $M$ then it will be $M∉V$.
We choose $P$ a random point from $V$, we note that quadrilateral $APBM$ contains two opposite right angles, so $APBM$ is a circular quadrilateral, for three points located on the same line, the circle passing through them is the same as the straight through them (the straight is a special case of the circle where the length of the radius is infinite  ), so the circle passing through points $A,P,B$ is the same as straight $V$, and since $APBM$ is a circular quadrilateral, the circle passing through points $A,P,B$ must also pass through the fourth point $M$, and therefore $M∈V$.
This is a contradiction, since $M∈V$ and $M∉V$ cannot be at the same time, and thus the assumption that $L,T$ intersect at point $M$ is wrong.

Comment: You say that "the two perpendiculars are parallel". "Parallel" by definition means two lines that do not intersect.

Comment: The theorem you want to prove is a particular case of [Prop. I-27 in Euclid's Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI27.html)) and doesn't need the parallel axiom.

Comment: To prove the parallel axiom you should prove the converse: "If two parallel lines $a$, $b$ are cut by a transversal $t$, and $a\perp t$, then also $b\perp t$."

Comment: Perhaps the wording is not completely accurate, especially since I use Google Translate. I do not think that there is a problem with using parallelism here, since with the definition of parallelism there is no intersection, but in this way the existence of parallelism has been proven in Euclidean geometry, where we have reached a contradiction that occurs when lines are not parallel.

Comment: I'll try proving the reverse imperative

Comment: Can you demonstrate that the assertion about two right angles in circular (cyclic?) quadrilaterals is independent of the parallel postulate? As far as I can tell, Euclid's Elements Book III Postulate 22 requires it.

Comment: You cannot prove the reverse imperative without making use of Euclid's Axiom 5 (or one of its many equivalent forms, which includes that "reverse imperattive"). This is exactly what was shown when it was discovered you can build a model of hyperbolic geometry within Euclidean geometry (the Poincare disk, for example). If Axiom 5 could be proven from the other axioms (including the ones Euclid used without recognizing), such a model would be impossible.